# "done() called multiple times" moongoose with mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

[See debugger output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VJ8R.png)

```
var expect = require('chai').expect  
var User = require('../../app/models/index.js').User  


describe('Model User', function(){  
  it('add a user', function(done){  
    var user = new User({  
      uname: 'cx',  
      password: 'cx'  
    })  

   user.save()    //Model#save()  return Promise
    .then(function(user,effectNum){  
       done()   //success state
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      done(error)  //fail state
    })
 })
})
```

Use Chai, Mocha, Moongoose
I test my code when learn moongodb. Seems to be correct
But I get a error:

```
   0 passing (2m)
   2 failing

   1) Model User add a user:
     Error: done() called multiple times

   2) Model User add a user:
     Error: done() called multiple times
```

why it call done multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The done() callback accepts an error, so you can try using it directly:

```
it('should add a user', function(done) {
      var user = new User({  
          uname: 'cx',  
          password: 'cx'  
      }); 

      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        done();
      });
});
```

Comment: Hi,Nikola B.  This is work! Thanks ! But How to solve problem with Promise? Model#save return a Promise

Answer (score 3):

```
describe('Model User', function(){


     it('add a user', function(done){
    var user = new User({
      uname: 'cx',
      password: 'cx'
    })

    user.save()
        .then(function(){
          assert(false)
        }).then(done,done)

  })
})

//or
describe('Model User', function(){
  it('add a user', function(){
    var user = new User({
      uname: 'cx',
      password: 'cx'
    })

   return  user.save()
        .then(function(){
          assert(false)
        })

  })
})
```

Mocha support Promise ^_^ ,My mistake